# Replace characters other then numbers and '-' sign using regex expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to add validation for a number type input box, for which I have tried the below codes,

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/ig,'');
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/ig,'');
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.\-]/g,'');
this.value = this.value.replace(/(?!-)[^0-9.]/g,'');
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.-]/g,'');
```

Actually I want to replace all the characters entered (other than numbers, '.' and '-') into the input box with blank. But none of the above are working for me. Please help.

Thanks and Regards,

Neha

Comment: `/[^0-9\.\-]/` works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ym74ypo8/. Your problem must lie outside of the Regex replacement. We cannot help you without seeing a more complete sample of your code.

Comment: Are you sure that `this` is referring to what you think it is?

Comment: Is your `this` inside of a jQuery callback? Then maybe you need something like `$(this).val($(this).val().replace('/[^0-9-.]/g', ''))`.

Comment: The question is way too unclear. Post the whole fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
value.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '');
```

The `^` at start of the inside or the brackets means "*replace all, but not that chars*". See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/06xvqj4z/1/) for a fiddle.

Comment: The already tried `/[^0-9\.\-]/` apparently, not any different than this answer.

Comment: Is my example working, or not? It is. So, if the regex is correct, there maybe anything other wrong. But this was the question, and this is the answer. :)

Comment: They have the same regular expression in the question, so why would this help? Clearly the problem is elsewhere, leading to this question being off-topic unless they add more information.

Comment: He didn't know what regex of the five shown was the right, now he does and can inspect if anything else went wrong. But as said before, the question was, what is the regex to do this. And this is still the answer for the question ...

Comment: And btw, it should be `value.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '');`

Answer (score 0):

The input type which I had used was a number
''

Hence it did not allow '-' sign.

Have changed it to text now.